# Mapping XML to Object with same tag names but different attributes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I am trying to convert the below XML string to a Java object using JAXB and eclipse persistence oxm annotations package.

```
<output>
     <rtEvent>
           <eventData name="tcppayload">
               <data>111111-000000-111111</data>
           </eventData>
           <eventData name="text">
               <data>ABCD</data>
           </eventData>
     </rtEvent>
</output>
```

However, the de-serialization does not seem to work. Can someone point out what I might be doing wrong.

Below is the class i'm using to deserialize the string into an object

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "output")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CameraTriggerOutput {

       @XmlPath("/rtEvent/eventData[@name=tcppayload]/data/text()")
       private String data;

 public void toXml() {
    try {
        JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(CameraTriggerOutput.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(this, System.out);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
 }
```

After running I get the following output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><output/>
```

Comment: what's error msg? or it just run without your expectation?

Comment: Updated the question with the output.

Comment: You have to make sure what you are doing.. you are trying to deserialize?  If so, you should get java object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I provide below the code with pure Jaxb, you can try.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "eventData")
public class EventData {

  private String name;

  private String data;

  @XmlElement(name = "data")
  public String getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "rtEvent")
public class RtEvent {

  private List<EventData> edataList;

  @XmlElement(name = "eventData")
  public List<EventData> getEdataList() {
    return edataList;
  }

  public void setEdataList(List<EventData> edataList) {
    this.edataList = edataList;
  }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "output")
public class Output {

  private RtEvent rtEvent;

  public RtEvent getRtEvent() {
    return rtEvent;
  }

  public void setRtEvent(RtEvent rtEvent) {
    this.rtEvent = rtEvent;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      EventData eData1 = new EventData();
      eData1.setData("111111-000000-111111");
      eData1.setName("tcppayload");

      EventData eData2 = new EventData();
      eData2.setData("ABCD");
      eData2.setName("text");

      List<EventData> eDataList = new ArrayList<>();
      eDataList.add(eData1);
      eDataList.add(eData2);

      RtEvent rtEvent = new RtEvent();
      rtEvent.setEdataList(eDataList);

      Output output = new Output();
      output.setRtEvent(rtEvent);

      JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Output.class);
      Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
      marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
      marshaller.marshal(output, System.out);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

You Jaxb only as it is part of java, there is no need to include any other annotations. You can make individual classes in your ide and you can test the class Output which has a main method.